# Import implicit namespace package works on one machine not the other

Tags: python-3.x

I have project structure as follow

- project

  - research

    - paper

      - script.py
  - tools

    - fetch.py
    - add.py

I can't seem to import `fetch.py` in `script.py` using

```
from tools import fetch.py

or 
import tools
```

This doesn't run on VSCode with python 3.7 but it ran on another machine with PyCharm with Conda. Both have the same working directory. at `/user/<my_name>/project`

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'

I expect it works

Comment: Have you used absolute import instead directly from tools? Here is something to help you out https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#absolute-imports

Comment: yes, I have tried "from tools.fetch import func1"
still returns No module named 'tools'

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out the answer with a bit of in-depth googling. Turn out it's a known issue with VSCode which explains why it worked in PyCharm.

https://github.com/Microsoft/python-language-server/issues/288